# Use mobile data only in Android app

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io, bind

I'd like to use mobile(3G or LTE) data only in my Android app.
Please correct my codes. 
I use socket.io library instead of java.net.socket. So, I don't know how to use:
network.bindSocket(). Because it is impossible to convert socket.io.Socket to java.net.Socket for bindSocket().

```
    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

    builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
    NetworkRequest networkRequest = builder.build();

    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                    connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);
                    boolean ret = ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get your network type

```
public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
    switch (networkType) {
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
            return "2G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
            return "3G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
            return "4G";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
}
```